# Calculating parameters from non linear regression of sum of exponentials

Tags: heteroscedasticity, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I am attempting to fit some data that seems to follow an equation that is the sum of two exponentials. When fitting with a single exponential the residual histogram is not normally distributed. The sum of two single exponentials with a weighting term fits the data well, however the parameters are very susceptible to initial guesses. I am fitting this equation to 60 different data sets to determine the parameters, so I am trying to find a general method to determine the parameters. A weighted least squared minimization is what I am currently doing, but depending on initial guesses and bounds it is likely to not give a good fit (based on distribution of residuals). So are there other techniques for fitting the data?

Equation I am using (with roughly 16000 points of $t, F(t)$ and determined variance at each time point): $$F(t) = F_0+(F_{eq}-F_0)A*e^{-k_1*t}+(F_{eq}-F_0)(1-A)*e^{-k_2*t}$$
Where $F_0$ and $F_{eq}$ are bounded in fitting and have initial estimates directly based on data (initial and endpoints). $1≥A≥0$ and $k_{1,2}≥0$

To be more specific I am fitting a kinetic process of binding to a protein. I am fitting this at multiple concentrations and then fitting $k_1$ and $k_2$ (which are actually $k_{obs1}$ and $k_{obs2}$) at multiple concentrations. If I take the values when the residuals aren't normally distributed and plot them, there is not a correlation between concentrations. If I force the values enough to give a normal distribution, then there is a correlation between concentrations (as there should be).

Here's a link to a csv containing a condensed version of one trace (averaged every ten values to ~1500 points). Scipy curve fit works fairly well here and gives me values of $F_0, F_{eq}, A, k_1, k_2 ≈ 0.9977, 0.00074, 0.8166, 0.0715, 0.271$, which gives me a reasonably good fit based on the distribution of residuals. However the provided answer gives me p = -2.0565 and q = -1154 assuming I've properly coded it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vLp4hGlXOv8kCXfuD39jIMiEQJQcGC-t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you joint to your question a representative example of data. Of course not 16000 points but a smaller number of points enough to be able to reproduce the difficulty that you encountered.

Comment: I'll edit my post shortly to do that, I'll take every ten points for a representative trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP added an example of data to his question it is  now possible to show the calculus using the method proposed in my first answer.

For me, the goal isn't to solve accurately the problem. The goal is to give an example of numerical calculus in full details so that everybody can reproduce it and be able to check each step. To make it easier we will not use the original data of 1500 points but a subset of only 20 points taken among them.

x=
1.0045
1.7445
2.4945
3.2445
3.9945
4.7445
5.4945
6.2445
6.9945
7.7445
8.4945
9.2445
9.9945
17.445
24.945
32.445
39.945
47.445
54.945
62.445

y=
0.89855
0.833921
0.774222
0.719953
0.674778
0.631464
0.592844
0.555447
0.521094
0.49169
0.462038
0.437067
0.412439
0.234885
0.136977
0.081586
0.049508
0.029161
0.017968
0.008837

[image]

Once your code is correctly running with this representative example you can use it with the whole data.

If a particular criteria of fitting (LMSE or LMSRE or other) is formally requiered you can use the approximate values of p,q,a,b,c obtained as very good initial values of parameters for a non-linear regression software with the specified criteria of fitting implemented into it. This answers to the question about avoiding "guessed" initial values of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you! I will likely do the suggestion of taking a subset to dynamically find initial parameters, which should allow a dynamic fitting. I'm not sure why the large set didn't work when I tried it but I will be able to figure it out now.

Comment: @cmay. Even with the large set  the method works verry well. It isn't a good idea to take a subset. The accuracy of the result is certainely better from the large set. If it doesn't work properly probably there is a bug in the code. May be a trouble in the two numerical integrations (calculus of the $S_k$ and $SS_k$ ? Are the points correcttly ranked ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I finally had time to go back and check and I had made some errors in my calculations of SSk (- instead of +). I have extended to calculate all parameters but I had one question. How would I go about calculating the error associated with the parameters determined by this? Packages such as SciPy.least_squares are able to give an error associated with these parameters but I do not know how to calculate them from a direct fitting like this.

Comment: Sorry, the method involving regression with integral equation is not developped enough today to answer to your question about the error associated to the parameters. As well as for taking account to different criteria of fitting one have to come back to the traditional iterative methods of nonlinear regression. I suppose that you could use SciPy.least_squarres with the advantage of good initial values of parameters previously obtained as above.

Comment: Thank you, I have now implemented that, my data is heteroscedastic as well since I have the variance at each time point. Before I was having issues with getting reasonable parameters without really narrowing the bounds of the regression (I do this fitting several times with varying conditions and compare parameters between them). With these initial parameters (which does ignore the variances) SciPy.curve_fit is able to get consistent parameters when it does a weighted regression. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The principle of a method which doesn't need initial guess is explained in this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

The example pp.71-73 is not directly applicable in your case. A small adaptation is necessary. See below :

[image]

The relationships of symbols are :

$a=F_0$ ; $b=(F_{eq}-F_0)A$ ; $c=(F_{eq}-F_0)(1-A)$ ; $p=-k_1$ ; $q=-k_2$ .

From the values of $a,b,c,p,q$ obtained it is easy to compute $F_0$ , $F_{eq}$ , $A$ , $k_1$ , $k_2$ .

If a representative data had been joint to the question I had checked to say if the method is convenient in your case and eventually I had adapt the method more specifically.

IN ADDITION , after the data was joint to the question :

With the whole data (1499 points) the numerical calculus following the above method leads to :

[image]

The points are drawn in red.

The fitted curve is drawn in blue.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing such simple formulas will generally work, especially because $p=-k_1$ implies $k_1$ is *negative,* whereas the model in the question requires positivity.

Comment: I don't think it: it's a property of the formula you wrote, following from $A\gt 0.$

Comment: I found this solution shortly after I posted the question, however on my data it was giving me q ~ -1700 if I remember correctly (definitely was a large negative number, <-1000). Whatever the value was, it gave several terms as 0 in the second matrix, making it impossible to invert. But I'll try it again with a subset of the data and post it in a few hours.

Comment: I just checked and it was p, q = -17.7, -11700. Ill update with representative data shortly and recalculate those values on the subset of data

Comment: I don't agree with the  values of p, q, that you got See my result ( above, in addition to my answer).

Comment: @JJacquelin You were right, I found the errors in my code for it. Thanks a lot. I had one follow up question in your other answer whenever you have time.

Comment: All's well that ends well.